# MySQL select first row then skip few

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to select first row then skip X next rows then select rest in one query. For example if I have (a,b,c,d,e) in table I need to select "a" (first row) then skip X=2 rows ("b", "c") and then select rest which is "d" and "e", all in one query. So the result would be a,d,e

Comment: One way would be `select * from your_table
order by colA
limit 1
union all
select * from your_table
order by colA
limit 3, 9999999`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select *
from
(
  select *, @rank := @rank + 1 as rank
  from your_table
  cross join (select @rank := 0) r
  order by colA
) tmp
where rank = 1
or rank > 3
```

or

```
select * from your_table 
order by colA 
limit 1 
union all 
select * from your_table 
order by colA 
limit 4, 9999999
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to generate a row number:

```
select 
  YourField,
  YourOtherField
from
(
  select id,
    YourField,
    YourOtherField,
    @row := @row + 1 as rownum
  from YourTable
  cross join (select @row:=0) c
  order by YourField -- The field you want to sort by when you say 'first' and 'fourth'
) d
where
  rownum = 1 or rownum >= 4
```